# Missing values not plotting with custom fill aesthetic scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

## Missing values not plotting with custom fill aesthetic scale

Hello SO! I’m hoping you can help me with this issue I
ran into while creating a custom color scale for `ggplot2`. I’m sorry
for the long-winded post–I followed the excellent posts from [Robert
Franssen](https://rjfranssen.io/blog/custom-color-palette/), [Simon
Jackson](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/creating-corporate-colour-palettes-for-ggplot2),
[Maddie Pickens](https://rpubs.com/mclaire19/ggplot2-custom-themes), and
the well-written documentation for
[`ggplot2`](https://ggplot2-book.org/).

### Load packages

Below are the packages I’m using:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(grDevices)
library(NHANES)
```

### Create vector of colors

Below I define a vector of colors:

```r
# define colors ----
pckg_colors <- c(
  ## dark blues ----
  `dark_blue_t3` = "#325777",
  `dark_blue_t2` = "#194266",
    `dark_blue_primary` = "#002E56", # primary
  `dark_blue_s2` = "#00294d",
  `dark_blue_s3` = "#002444",
  ## purples ----
  `purple_t3` = "#5d63ac",
  `purple_t2` = "#4950a2",
      `purple_primary` = "#353D98", # primary
  `purple_s2` = "#2f3688",
  `purple_s3` = "#2a3079",
  ## blues ----
  `blue_t3` = "#3272af",
  `blue_t2` = "#1961a5",
      `blue_primary` = "#00509C", # primary
  `blue_s2` = "#00488c",
  `blue_s3` = "#00407c",
  ## violets ----
  `violet_t3` = "#ba4da4",
  `violet_t2` = "#b13799",
      `violet_primary` = "#A9218E", # primary
  `violet_s2` = "#981d7f",
  `violet_s3` = "#871a71",
  ## reds ----
  `red_t3` = "#f15971",
  `red_t2` = "#ef445f",
      `red_primary` = "#EE304E", # primary
  `red_s2` = "#d62b46", 
  `red_s3` = "#be263e",
  ## oranges ----
  `orange_t3` = "#f4845a",
  `orange_t2` = "#f37545",
      `orange_primary` = "#F26631", # primary
  `orange_s2` = "#d95b2c",
  `orange_s3` = "#c15127")
# Define function for extracting colors ----
pckg_cols <- function(...) {
  cols <- c(...)
  if (is.null(cols))
    return(pckg_colors)
  pckg_colors[cols]
}
# Define list of palettes ----
pckg_palettes <- list(
  `primary` = pckg_cols(
    "dark_blue_primary", "purple_primary", "blue_primary", 
    "violet_primary", "red_primary", "orange_primary"
  ),
  `light` = pckg_cols(
    "dark_blue_t3", "dark_blue_t2", "purple_t3", "purple_t2", 
    "blue_t3", "blue_t2", "violet_t3", "violet_t2", 
    "red_t3", "red_t2", "orange_t3", "orange_t2"
  ),
  `dark` = pckg_cols(
    "dark_blue_s2", "dark_blue_s3", "purple_s2", "purple_s3", 
    "blue_s2", "blue_s3", "violet_s2", "violet_s3", 
    "red_s2", "red_s3", "orange_s2", "orange_s3"
  ),
  `all` = pckg_cols(
    "dark_blue_t3", "dark_blue_t2", "dark_blue_primary", 
    "dark_blue_s2", "dark_blue_s3", 
    "purple_t3", "purple_t2", "purple_primary", 
    "purple_s2", "purple_s3", 
    "blue_t3", "blue_t2", "blue_primary", 
    "blue_s2", "blue_s3", 
    "violet_t3", "violet_t2", "violet_primary", 
    "violet_s2", "violet_s3", 
    "red_t3", "red_t2", "red_primary", 
    "red_s2", "red_s3",
    "orange_t3", "orange_t2", "orange_primary", 
    "orange_s2", "orange_s3"
  )
)
# Define function for extracting colors ----
pckg_pal <- function(palette = "main", reverse = FALSE, ...) {
  pal <- pckg_palettes[[palette]]
  if (reverse) pal <- rev(pal)
  grDevices::colorRampPalette(colors = pal, ...)
}
# Define color scale 
scale_color_pckg <- function(palette = "main", discrete = TRUE, reverse = FALSE, ...) {
    pal <- pckg_pal(palette = palette, reverse = reverse)
    
    if (discrete) {
      ggplot2::discrete_scale(aesthetics = "colour", 
        scale_name = paste0("pckg_", palette), palette = pal, ...)
    } else {
      ggplot2::scale_color_gradientn(colours = pal(256), ...)
    }
}
# Define fill scale 
scale_fill_pckg <- function(palette = "main", discrete = TRUE, reverse = FALSE, ...) {
  pal <- pckg_pal(palette = palette, reverse = reverse)
  if (discrete) {
    ggplot2::discrete_scale(aesthetics = "fill", 
      scale_name = paste0("pckg_", palette), palette = pal, ...)
  } else {
    ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pal(256), ...)
  }
}
```

Test this in a plot using the `nhanes` data (a subset of the
[NHANES](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NHANES/NHANES.pdf)
data).

```r
nhanes <- NHANES::NHANES %>% janitor::clean_names()
ggplot(data = nhanes, 
  mapping = aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1/5, color = pckg_cols("red_s2"))
```

```
## Warning: Removed 366 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data = nhanes, 
  mapping = aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1/5, color = pckg_cols("purple_t2"))
```

```
## Warning: Removed 366 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

On both of these I wee the
`## Warning: Removed 366 rows containing missing values (geom_point).`

## Color aesthetic

```r
ggplot(data = nhanes, 
  mapping = aes(x = height, y = weight, color = age)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_pckg(discrete = FALSE, palette = "light")
```

```
## Warning: Removed 366 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

I also see
`## Warning: Removed 366 rows containing missing values (geom_point).`

## Fill aesthetic

When I test the `fill` aesthetic, I can pass it two categorical
variables.

```r
nhanes %>% 
  count(race1)
```

```
## # A tibble: 5 × 2
##   race1        n
##   <fct>    <int>
## 1 Black     1197
## 2 Hispanic   610
## 3 Mexican   1015
## 4 White     6372
## 5 Other      806
```

```r
ggplot(data = nhanes, 
  mapping = aes(x = race1, fill = race1)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_fill_pckg(palette = "light", guide = "none")
```

[image]

But when I can pass it two variables with missing values…

```r
nhanes %>% 
  count(race3)
```

```
## # A tibble: 7 × 2
##   race3        n
##   <fct>    <int>
## 1 Asian      288
## 2 Black      589
## 3 Hispanic   350
## 4 Mexican    480
## 5 White     3135
## 6 Other      158
## 7 <NA>      5000
```

```r
ggplot(data = nhanes, 
  mapping = aes(x = race3, fill = race3)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_fill_pckg(palette = "primary", guide = "none")
```

[image]

Here I see the missing values for `race3` aren’t plotted with this
scale? Do I need to provide an argument to `na.translate` or `na.value`
in the `discrete_scale()` function?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to follow up and say I figured this out by adding the `na.value = "grey50"` argument to both scale functions.

```r
scale_color_pckg <- function(palette = "main", discrete = TRUE, reverse = FALSE, ...) {
    pal <- pckg_pal(palette = palette, reverse = reverse)
    
    if (discrete) {
      ggplot2::discrete_scale(aesthetics = "colour", 
        scale_name = paste0("pckg_", palette), palette = pal, na.value = "grey50", ...)
    } else {
      ggplot2::scale_color_gradientn(colours = pal(256), na.value = "grey50", ...)
    }
}
scale_fill_pckg <- function(palette = "main", discrete = TRUE, reverse = FALSE, ...) {
  pal <- pckg_pal(palette = palette, reverse = reverse)
  if (discrete) {
    ggplot2::discrete_scale(aesthetics = "fill", 
      scale_name = paste0("pckg_", palette), palette = pal, na.value = "grey50", ...)
  } else {
    ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pal(256), na.value = "grey50", ...)
  }
}

ggplot(data = nhanes, 
  mapping = aes(x = race3, fill = race3)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_fill_pckg(palette = "primary", guide = "none")
```

[image]